# Use loops to create small multiples in subplots with groupby.sum?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas-groupby

I'd like to create 5 x 7 subplots to accommodate 34 line charts for each `Planning Authority` with a-axis as `Permission Financial Year` and y-value as `sum` of `Net additional units`

I have used the `groupby`.sum to find out the sum of net additional units by each authority in each year, and manually created a few subplots for illustration. However, I am sure there must be some more efficient ways like using  `loop` to automate/simplify the generation of all the charts.

Hope someone can help. Many thanks.

[image]
[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy.random import randint
from numpy.random import randint

pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', 0)

df = pd.read_csv('LDD Permissions for Datastore - Final selected updated 19.04.2020 - including checked05.05 -used.csv', encoding='mac_roman')

#Aggregate the sum of net additional units by Permission Fianacial Year and Planning Authority
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 1000)
total_permitted_unit_per_year = df.groupby(['Permission Financial Year','Planning Authority']).sum()['Net additional units'].unstack(-1)

#Generate subplots of net additional units from 2009 to 2019 for each Planning Authority
plt.rc('xtick',labelsize=10)
plt.rc('ytick',labelsize=10)

fig = plt.figure()
plt.figure(figsize=(200, 800))

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(7,5,1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(7,5,2)
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(7,5,3)
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(7,5,4)
ax5 = fig.add_subplot(7,5,5)
ax6 = fig.add_subplot(7,5,6)
ax7 = fig.add_subplot(7,5,7)
ax8 = fig.add_subplot(7,5,8)
ax9 = fig.add_subplot(7,5,9)
ax10 = fig.add_subplot(7,5,10)
ax11 = fig.add_subplot(7,5,11)
ax12 = fig.add_subplot(7,5,12)

total_permitted_unit_per_year.plot(y='Barking and Dagenham', ax=ax1, legend=False, marker='.', markersize=5, figsize=(30,15))
ax1.set_title('Barking and Dagenham')
ax1.set_ylim([0, 350])

total_permitted_unit_per_year.plot(y='Barnet', ax=ax2, legend=False, marker='.', markersize=5, figsize=(30,15))
ax2.set_title('Barnet')
ax2.set_ylim([0, 350])

total_permitted_unit_per_year.plot(y='Bexley', ax=ax3, legend=False, marker='.', markersize=5, figsize=(30,15))
ax3.set_title('Bexley')
ax3.set_ylim([0, 350])

total_permitted_unit_per_year.plot(y='Sutton', ax=ax4, legend=False, marker='.', markersize=5, figsize=(30,15))
ax4.set_title('Sutton')
ax4.set_ylim([0, 350])

total_permitted_unit_per_year.plot(y='Merton', ax=ax5, legend=False, marker='.', markersize=5)
ax5.set_title("Merton")
ax5.set_ylim([0, 350])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your code after the `plt.figure` line with:

```
for col_num in range(1, 13):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(7, 5, col_num)
    ax.set_title(total_permitted_unit_per_year.columns[col_num])
    ax.set_ylim([0, 350])
    total_permitted_unit_per_year.plot(y=total_permitted_unit_per_year.columns[col_num], ax=ax, legend=False, marker='.', markersize=5, figsize=(30,15))
```

Replace 13 with the number of columns you want to plot + 1, which may just be `len(total_permitted_unit_per_year.columns)+1`

If you want to just plot certain columns in a certain order, you do something like this:

```
pa = ['Croyden', ... ] # fill it out with the column names
for i in range(len(pa)):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(7, 5, i)
    ax.set_title(pa[i])
    ax.set_ylim([0, 350])
    total_permitted_unit_per_year.plot(y=pa[i], ax=ax, legend=False, marker='.', markersize=5, figsize=(30,15))
```

Comment: It works perfectly. Thank you, Imran!! Just a follow-up question. The subplots generated from the loop are now arranged in alphabetical order. Is there any way I can tailor a specific order? For instance, via a list specifying the order of  `Planning Authority`?

Comment: The subplots are in the order the columns appear in the dataframe (which just happens to be alphabetical). Is `Planning Authority` a list and how is it ordered?

Comment: At the moment, `Planning Authority` is one of the **original columns** in the dataset. Each row has a value. There are 34 different values.  I have used `groupby` so each value in `Planning Authority` is a different column in the `groupby` data frame.